# Apiversion v2 not valid

Tags: kubernetes, hadoop, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install hadoop into k8s (minikube) with Helm chart by the help of this :

[github link](https://github.com/Gradiant/bigdata-charts)

And every time i run this command `install helm --name hdfs bigdata-gradiant/hdfs` i get this error :

Error : apiVersion 'v2' is not valid. The value must be 'v1'

Comment: Try updating your helm client, maybe? Checking hdfs charts source, the only v2 I find is that in the Chart.yaml: none regarding Kubernetes objects.

Comment: it's already v2, i think i have to change the version into 1, have you any idea ?

Comment: I just told you my idea. Chart.yaml is the only occurence of a v2. Your error tells "apiVersion v2 is not valid, try v1". This suggests you're running an older version of the helm client. Try updating your client.

Comment: @SYN Client : &version: v2.17.0 , is not about client version i guess

Comment: ... I must insist, you should download the last client. https://github.com/helm/helm/releases . v3 has been there for years now. If you still have that "tiller" deployment: you can get rid of it.

Comment: Read the official documentation? https://hadoop.apache.org/ozone/docs/1.0.0/start/minikube.html